# user tried to access amazon workspace via browser and providing registration code then user got ERROR_TYPE_WARPDRIVE error

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace

user tried to access amazon workspace via browser and providing registration code then user got ERROR_TYPE_WARPDRIVE error. As a administrator i ch checked registration code with directory. both codes are same. please help how to resolve the issue.

please share the solution

Comment: I am also seeing the same issue.
Was trying to launch an Ubuntu 22.04 instance and the thin client they supply would try to connect then instantly disconnect.  I thought I would check the web ui to see if this was something else but doesn't seem to be happy there either.

Comment: Thank a lot Mr.Jason Brodie for your response.
You can try reboot once and then ask user to access once again.

Comment: It appears this was an issue on AWS side that was resolved the next day.